# Как отобразить данные в iframe через атрибут src в Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

Пытаюсь отобразить в iframe простую верстку:

```
<iframe name="iFramePreview"
        height="850"
        width="850"
        src='data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html><body>Hello World' />
```

Во-всех **нормальных** браузерах работает, кроме IE.

Как исправить это?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам подойдет решение с вынесением содержания Вашего `iframe` в отдельный `*.htm` файл?

Создал файл `hello.htm`

содержание:

```
<html><body>Hello World</body></html>
```

Ваш код изменил на:

```
<iframe name="iFramePreview"
    height="850"
    width="850"
    src='hello.htm' />
```

Профит.

Comment: нет, такой вариант не подходит к сожалению. Содержимое нужно передавать ИМЕННО в src не в качестве документа